# Should a pandas dataframe column be converted in some way before passing it to a scikit learn regressor?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe and passing `df[list_of_columns]` as X and `df[[single_column]]` as `Y` to a Random Forest regressor.

What does the following warnning mean and what should be done to resolve it?

```
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().   probas = cfr.fit(trainset_X, trainset_Y).predict(testset_X)
```

Comment: Why do you have double square brackets around `single_column`?

Comment: 'single_column' has the target column name, and pandas column selection requires a list so the column name is wrapped with square brackets

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you omitted them, you would not have gotten the warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply check the shape of your `Y` variable, it should be a one-dimensional object, and you are probably passing something with more (possibly trivial) dimensions. Reshape it to the form of list/1d array.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `df.single_column.values` or `df['single_column'].values` to get the underlying numpy array of your series (which, in this case, should also have the correct 1D-shape as mentioned by lejlot).

Answer (score 5):

Actually the warning tells you exactly what is the problem:

You pass a 2d array which happened to be in the form `(X, 1)`, but the method expects a 1d array and has to be in the form `(X, )`.

Moreover the warning tells you what to do to transform to the form you need: `y.values.ravel()`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'`

Comment: @mehaase it was not really intended to be blindly copypasted. This was more of an explanation what is going on and why. For a blind copypaste - use this: `y.values.ravel()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Y = df[[single_column]].values.ravel()` solves `DataConversionWarning` for me.