# DataConversionWarning fitting RandomForestRegressor in Scikit

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to fit a RandomForestRegressor to my training set,

```
rfr.fit(train_X , train_y)
```

but keep getting the following warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/**main**.py:1: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
>     if **name** == '**main**':

I am using Pandas, and therefore assumed that the training set might need to be in numpy arrays, so called .values:

```
train_y = train[label].values
train_X = train[features].values
```

Checking to see the type, and shape:

```
print type(train_X), train_X.shape
print type(train_y), train_y.shape
```

Returns:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (20457, 44)  
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (20457, 1)
```

Not really sure what to do next, only found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868664/should-a-pandas-dataframe-column-be-converted-in-some-way-before-passing-it-to-a) but it wasn't much help.

It does actually output a result, but I have no idea if it is the right one. With cross validation, it keeps creating that warning over and over again.

Comment: So did you try `rfr.fit(train_X , train_y.values)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
.values is already in the train_y = train[label].values
(i have tried in the format you suggest, but have the same result)

Comment: Try this `rfr.fit(train_X , train_y.values.ravel())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning tells you exactly what to do, right?
 What is the question? If the results are correct despite the warning? Yes they are, because what you mean is using a 1d vector y.

How to get rid of the warning? If you meant y to be a 1d vector and not a column of a matrix, use y.ravel() as the warning says.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says, we wanna change the dimension from (N,1) to (N,). 
we can use numpy's ravel function.

Use np.ravel(train_y) instead of train_y.

you may Try train_y.reshape((-1,)) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try like  `y.shape=y.shape[0]`, because you should make `y.shape` like `(20457,)`, not `(20457,1)`